# ArcMap AddIn Build Error when referencing external ActiveX Interface in VS2010

Tags: arcobjects, arcmap, add-in, visual-studio

If the "Register for COM interop" is unchecked the projects builds without errors.

[image: VS2010 Project Properties Build Tab]

But I have to reference external ActiveX Interface in my project so I have to have that check-box checked. I am getting the build error:

Cannot register assembly "...\MyCustomArcMapAddIn.dll". Could not load file or assembly 'ESRI.ArcGIS.Desktop.AddIns, Version=10.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8fc3cc631e44ad86' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Is there workaround here?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The newer type of ArcGIS Add-in's do not get registered for COM interop. However, You can use ActiveX controls in an Add-in without using this option. The controls should be installed separately before the Add-in. For example, you can use Microsoft ReportViewer with an add-in if it is installed on the machine already.

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense. I built the ActiveX in separate project, installed it separately and I can use it without checking that option  "Register for COM interop"